# In which cases can I use foo.bar but not [foo bar]

Tags: objective-c

I still struggle to understand the difference between the too message sending syntaxes in objc. I know that in certain cases only the is allowed. what is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Dot syntax is just syntactic sugar around `[foo bar]`. Technically you can use it anywhere to call methods with no parameters (after all property getters ARE methods with no parameters). E.g. this works but looks strange:)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    super.viewDidLoad
    //..
}
```

But from programming style guide you should only using it when accessing properties.

Edit: 
this also works for assignments, assignment is calling method with single parameter:

```
//..
self.viewDidLoad = @"Test";
//..

- (void)setViewDidLoad:(NSString *)a
{
    NSLog(@"%@", a);
}
```

Comment: Really? Does `super.viewDidLoad` work? Have you tried this?

Comment: This answer is correct. @SunilChauhan `super.viewDidLoad` works, but generates a compiler warning